# Multiple adapters on Moshi

Tags: android, moshi

I wanted to ask for certain if this is legal in Moshi to have two adapters on one Moshi - I'm not getting errors, but I found on some devices there is a problem:

```
Moshi moshi = new Moshi.Builder()
                .add(new CallLogJsonAdapter())
                .add(new ContactJsonAdapter())
                .build();
```

Comment: please provide your logcate

Comment: There is no LogCat - for me it's working, but sometimes I see NPE from other users (mainly Samsung).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moshi permits as many adapters as you need. In the unusual event that multiple classes adapt the same type, the one you add first takes precedence.

Comment: Where is this documented that the order matters? Seems like a big issue on Kotlin if you are using KotlinJsonAdapterFactory().